# Adding Views to an Android Viewgroup Programmatically

Tags: android, view, viewgroup

This seems to be a common question yet documentation is very hard to find. I'm looking for examples that show me how to create my own view group (preferably by extending an already existing one) and then add views programmaticly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)

ViewGroup is abstract, and its [onLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onLayout%28boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) is abstract too. So you need to provide an implementation for onLayout where you do assign a position at every child (View) of the viewgroup.